# how can I make Firebug wrap text in the Script panel?

Tags: firebug

I'm trying to debug a web script using Firebug.  The code does not have a carriage return at the end of each statement.  The whole script occupies maybe 5-10 lines in the Firebug script viewer, but each line is very long.

This is inconvenient because when I search for an event or function, I have to scroll horizontally to find the actual search result.

Is there any way to tell Firebug to wrap the code text so that everything is in view without having to scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug 2.0 will have a pretty-print feature, which reformats minified JavaScript. See the [blog post for the alpha 2](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/04/04/firebug-2-0-alpha-2/). You can try it out by downloading the alpha release here:

https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/2.0/

Though note that it requires at least Firefox 30, which is currently available as [Aurora version](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/aurora/).